# Is it possible to execute an array numbers as a function?

Tags: c++, c, linux, elf

Long story short, I have an array of integers that represents the .text section of an ELF binary with one function. I want to execute this function. I have run this command prior to trying to execute the command:

```
mprotect(function, sHeader.sh_size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
```

thinking that it might resolve permission issues, but it still segfaults when i try to run it:

```
int (*fp)(int, int) = (int (*)(int, int))getFunc("t.o");
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
cout << fp(a, b) << "\n";
```

but it still segfaults when i try to run it:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000603010 in ?? ()
```

is there anything I missed?

objdump of the function i'm trying to execute:

```
0000000000000000 <mult>:
mult():
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
   a:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   d:   0f af 45 f8             imul   -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  11:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  12:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Can't you use `dlopen` as I explained in my answer?

Comment: You cannot be sure that `mult` is at the very start of `.text` segment. At the very least, you need to get the `mult` symbol from your `t.so`, basically duplicating what `dlopen` and `dlsym` do

Comment: In this case though, it is. I made sure of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) object file contains [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29) information, and very probably its `.text` section contains code to be relocated, so that code won't run as is. Use the `objdump` and `readelf` commands to explore it. If you really want to load it the way you do, you should process the relocation information, which is complex, processor specific, and tedious. If you really want to spend weeks doing this, study the x86-64 [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). But using `dlopen` of a `.so` then `dlsym` is much simpler (because `dlopen` is doing the relocation after having  `mmap`-ed segments from `t.so`), see below.

<sup>The x86-64 ABI used to be on http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf but that site don't work today</sup>

What is `getFunc`? How do you do relocation inside your `t.o`? Why can't you have a `t.so` shared object (e.g. compiled with `gcc -Wall -fPIC -O -shared t.c -o t.so`) then load it using [dlopen(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and `dlsym(3)` e.g.

```
typedef int functionsig_t (int, int);
void* dlh = dlopen("./t.so", RTLD_NOW);
if (!dlh) {
   fprintf(stderr, "dlopen t.so failed with %s\n", dlerror());
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
};
functionsig_t* fp = (functionsig_t*) dlsym(dlh, "myfunc");
if (!fp) {
   fprintf(stderr, "dlsym myfunc failed with %s\n", dlerror());
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE),
}
// now you can call fp
int res = (*fp) (1,2);
```

Once the `fp` returned and no call stack frames exist using any function in `t.so` you can `dlclose(dlh);` which would `munmap` the segments from `t.so`. You could avoid calling `dlclose` (that would usually make an insignificant leak of process address space; see the file `/proc/1234/maps` for process of pid 1234), especially if you don't `dlopen` a big lot of shared objects.

If the `t.so` plugin calls functions from your main program, you want that main program to be linked with the `-rdynamic` option to `ld` or `gcc`

If `t.so` has been compiled from some C++ source, it should declare

```
 extern "C" int myfunc(int,int);
```

because of [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) done by `g++`

My [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) program shows that you can do many hundreds of thousands of `dlopen`-s in a Linux process. It works by generating "random" C code, compiling it into some `.so`, and `dlopen`-ing that `.so` file, then repeating that many times.

If you don't want the burden of compiling a `.c` or `.cc` code into a `.so` plugin, you could consider in-memory just-in-time code generation using [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [asmjit](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/), [libjit](http://freecode.com/projects/libjit), [GNU lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) etc...

Comment: I guess the .so route is the way you're really supposed to go in this situation, i guess i never thought of it.

Comment: Yes.... And using `dlopen` is much more portable than what you are trying to achieve....

Comment: The object dump shows code with no relocatable references. The problem in this case was more likely that the `getFunc` routine read the object file literally, but the object file is structured with data that describes the sections; the bytes for the text section are not directly at the start of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing relocation. The binary doesn't contain absolute addresses, but offsets.

When a binary is loaded, the OS relocates the function pointers (and all other symbols) by adding the allocated segment address to the offsets in the binary.

Comment: Let's say: most likely missing relocation. I can't say what's really inside your getFunc. But if it's that advanced, you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: The function I'm loading is very simple, and makes no reference to anything but the parameters it's being passed. I didn't think that location would be an issue in this case.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your function has no relocation and no external references....? (The compiler could add hidden calls). And it is **relocation** not "location"!

Comment: Yes, i'm fairly sure. i'll put the objdump in the main question